# Assign Substr of a string to a variable

Tags: unix, ksh

I am new to unix script. i am asked to modify a ksh script.

it requires i assign a substring of a string to another variable. I tried below and its not working

```
  GET_OLDEST_FILE=`ls -ltr *$FILE_PATTERN* | head -1 | awk '{print $9}'`
  echo "Oldest File in Dir " $GET_OLDEST_FILE
  TIMESTAMP_ON_FILE=substr(${GET_OLDEST_FILE},1,17)
  echo "Timestamp on file is " $TIMESTAMP_ON_FILE
```

suggest a way to make the assign work

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/guides.html - look for Advanced Bash scripting guide. ksh might be a bit different though.

Comment: thanks @Hannu this worked TIMESTAMP_ON_FILE=`echo ${GET_OLDEST_FILE:0:17}`

Comment: That should be `TIMESTAMP_ON_FILE=${GET_OLDEST_FILE:0:17}` - your construct is unnecessarily complex. But my `ksh` documentation does not include `${::}` expansion: it is a feature of `bash`.

Comment: What would work without `${::}` is `TIMESTAMP_ON_FILE=$(printf ".5s" "$GET_OLDEST_FILE")`. Here I have used `$()` instead of back-quotes because the latter are used for code segments when commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://tldp.org/guides.html - look for Advanced Bash scripting guide. ksh might be a bit different though.

There is an entire section on string manipulation in that guide.

`alphas="abcdefg";echo ${alphas:3:2}` will print `de`, i.e. two chars, starting with the fourth (0 is the first) from $alphas.